# Grid view Bind Problem when using List()

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview, paging

**The .aspx:**

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvFirst" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
        AllowPaging="true" 
        ondatabound="gvFirst_DataBound" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ProductID"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="ProductName" />
        </Columns>
        <PagerTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlPager" runat="server">
            </asp:Panel>
        </PagerTemplate>
    </asp:GridView>
```

**The .cs:**

```
 public class Productinformation
    {
     public int PID
     {
         get;
         set;
     }
     public string PName
     {
         get;
         set;
     }
    }
       using (NorthWindDataContext _NorthWindDataContext = new NorthWindDataContext())
        {
            Proinfo = new List<Productinformation>();
            Proinfo = (from p in _NorthWindDataContext.Products
                       select new Productinformation
                       {
                           PID = p.ProductID,
                           PName = p.ProductName,
                       }).ToList();

            gvFirst.DataSource =  Proinfo.Take(PageSize) ;
            gvFirst.DataBind();
        }
```

`Proinfo` variable is declared globally. Now When i run this code, it shows me  the following error :

> the data source does not support server-side data paging

If i use var type of variable then it is worked but
we can't declare var type of variable globally,so if i used it, then i have to call this method every time in paging. and i don't want to use `Objectdatasource`.

Comment: Hy , you solve my problem but one thing that i can't understand       List<Productinformation> Proinfo = new List<Productinformation>();
                Proinfo = (from p in _NorthWindDataContext.Products
                           select new Productinformation
                           {
                               PID = p.ProductID,
                               PName = p.ProductName,
                           }).ToList();            gvFirst.DataSource = Proinfo .Take(5); Then required to conver this inlist

Comment: var Pro = from p in _NorthWindDataContext.Products
                          select new Productinformation
                          {
                              PID = p.ProductID,
                              PName = p.ProductName,
                          };
                gvFirst.DataSource = Pro.Take(5);
                gvFirst.DataBind(); Then i don't require to convert this in ToList in both cases Take(5) return iEnurable...... pls help me to understand solution u have given...

Comment: If you remove the `AllowPaging` property, both of your code version will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must return a List to the `gvFirst` using `ToList()` method. So try this:

```
gvFirst.DataSource =  Proinfo.Take(PageSize).ToList();
```

*Explanation*:

Because on the `gvFirst` you set the property `AllowPaging="true"` than the paging can be used with any data source object that implements `ICollection` interface.

`ProInfo.Take(PageSize)` returns an `IEnumerable` and this is why you need to call the `ToList()` method.

Answer (score 1):

If you globaly declare Proinfo as a ICollection

```
private ICollection<Productinformation> Proinfo = null
```

Then then you use the .Take method you get the result as a enumerable that does not support paging so you have to convert it to a List that inherit from the ICollection.

```
gvFirst.DataSource =  Proinfo.Take(PageSize).ToList();
```